# Netbeans doesn't include resources, when opening a project

Tags: netbeans

When opening a project folder, on a different computer, Netbeans doesn't include the libraries of the project, even if they are all in the dist/lib folder.

Can I do anything to make deployment easier? So that the the user wouldn't have to import all the libraries again, on opening the project.

Comment: Not sure with a regular Java application project, but with a Maven Java Application project you can `build with dependencies`

Comment: Know about Maven, but sadly this is only a normal Java project.